# Qt -sysroot, -prefix, -extprefix and -hostprefix options

Tags: qt, cross-compiling, qmake

What is the correct way to use `-prefix` `-extprefix` and `-hostprefix` options to cross compile Qt5?
I have `sysroot` dir for my arm board. And I have no problems with cross compiling Qt for ARM except one - I can't figure out how to specify installation path to directory on my host machine (not whitin sysroot). Every combination of `-[..]prefix` flags trying to install Qt on board. There is not much disk space on board, so I want install Qt locally.

It's my current config:
    `./configure -opengl es2 -nomake tests -no-libjpeg -skip qtwebkit -skip qtwebkit-examples -no-xcb -device linux-jetson-tk1-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot /mnt/jetson_tk1_sysroot -hostprefix /home/alan/work/qt/qt_5.5.1_arm_cross_compiled -make libs -debug -v`

I'm already read this SO [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22540239/what-would-be-a-pratical-example-of-sysroot-and-prefix-options-for-qt), Qt [docs](https://gist.github.com/arraytools/604e5bc5b0c56c1cfb30) and google a lot.
I'm running Ubuntu on both host and target if it's matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install step targets the directory specified by `extprefix` which is optional and defaults to `sysroot/prefix`. Defining extprefix to point some directory in the host should prevent you from polluting your sysroot. `hostprefix` allows separating host tools like qmake from target binaries. When given, such tools will be installed under the specified directory instead of extprefix.

Using these prefix flags keeps your sysroot clean and separates device binaries and host tools:

```
export INSTALLPATH=/home/alan/work/qt/qt_5.5.1_arm_cross_compiled
./configure ... -extprefix $INSTALLPATH/binaries -hostprefix $INSTALLPATH/tools
```